# com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, database, nosql

I assumed this question was asked several times but I had to reask it again. Because solutions provided for this question did not give me an exact answer to get rid of this bloody error.

I use `mongo-java-driver-2.12.4` and `mongo.jar` when I try to insert document to db I get following error. Any help is appreciated.

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27000, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}, {address=127.0.0.1:27001, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}, {address=127.0.0.1:27002, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
```

Code :

```
    public class MongoDbConnectDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // To connect to mongodb server
        try {

             List<ServerAddress> lstServer = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
             lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27000));
             lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27002));
             lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27001));
             MongoClient  mongoClient = new MongoClient(lstServer);

            // Now connect to your database
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
            System.out.println("connect to database successfully");

            DBCollection coll = db.createCollection("mycol", null);
            System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

            DBCollection colReceived= db.getCollection("mycol");
            System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

            BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB").
                    append("description", "database").
                    append("likes", 100).
                    append("url", "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/").
                    append("by", "tutorials point");

            colReceived.insert(doc);
                 System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't do any thing, just restart the machine,
Restart work for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You obtain a Connection refused. Are you sure mongod is running?

Try to connect with mongoclient:

> mongo 127.0.0.1:27000/test

and this for all the three instances (27000, 27002, 27001).

If you have problem also with mongoclient, check your logs.

Answer (score 8):

another reason for this error can be that the version of mongo-java-driver is not compatible with your mongo application. My case : I was using mongo-java-driver version 2.12.3 with mongo 3.0.8 -> doesn't work. (https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java)

Answer (score 3):

**[Here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/09/commongodbmongotimeoutexception-timed.html)** is all the possible reason for this error are listed. In my case it was due to replicaset not initialised. Initialise replicaset using `rs.initiate()`. 
In my case I used the volume created from production data and used it in staging. Since the `local` db was having old replicaset config, it was not able to become PRIMARY. I did the following thing to make it PRIMARY:

```
>use local
> db.dropDatabase();
{ "dropped" : "local", "ok" : 1 }
> rs.initiate()
>myrepl:PRMIARY
```

Now the client was able to connect and perform read/write operations.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a snippet that might give a basic idea.

```
package com.mkyong.core;


import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;


public class MongoTest {
    static DBCollection table;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongo = null;
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DB db = mongo.getDB("lending");

         table = db.getCollection("bureaudata");
    
            
        /**** Find and display ****/
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("id", "63057298");

        DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }

    }
}
```