# MongoTimeoutException on spring-boot 2.6.3 and reactive mongo during writes

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a Spring Boot application connecting by the reactive driver to a MongoDB replica set - 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes.

After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.5.7 to 2.6.3 (driver version upgraded from 4.2.3 to 4.4.1), strange exceptions started to occur during service work under load.

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 120000 ms while
> waiting for a connection to server
> mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017

About 10% of writes to DB failes with an exception. Others request finishes successfully.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

UPD.

Migrating to boot 2.6.4 solved the problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432880/com-mongodb-mongotimeoutexception-timed-out-after-10000-ms-while-waiting-to-con)

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: @pringi unfortunately not.

Comment: @varman we use 17 version by azul. service is fully reactive based on netty and webflux

Comment: we are facing the same issue but we are already using spring boot 2.6.4